# Compression analysis in snowflake

Tags: compression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In redshift, we can run "analyze compression " . This gives us information on what % compression happened for each column. Do we have anything similar to that command in snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of key concepts of Snowflake is automatic storage handling:

[Database Storage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage)

> **When data is loaded into Snowflake, Snowflake reorganizes that data into its internal optimized, compressed, columnar format.** Snowflake stores this optimized data in cloud storage.
>
> Snowflake manages all aspects of how this data is stored — the organization, file size, structure, **compression**, metadata, statistics, and other aspects of data storage are handled by Snowflake. The data objects stored by Snowflake are not directly visible nor accessible by customers; they are only accessible through SQL query operations run using Snowflake.

[Benefits of Micro-partitioning](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#benefits-of-micro-partitioning)

> The benefits of Snowflake’s approach to partitioning table data include:
>
> - As the name suggests, micro-partitions are small in size (50 to 500 MB, before compression), which enables extremely efficient DML and fine-grained pruning for faster queries.
>
> ...
>
> - Columns are also compressed individually within micro-partitions. **Snowflake automatically determines the most efficient compression algorithm for the columns in each micro-partition.**

---

If the goal of  "ANALYZE COMPRESSION" is to find potential disk reduction gains that process is already done.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the chosen schema and indexing, Snowflake can achieve different compression performance. It would be useful to have more compression related metrics to optimize it, since I find that storage is not that cheap.